# Creating an array of products in JSON-LD

Tags: seo, json-ld, structured-data

Can someone spot what's wrong with my code below? (It doesn't validate in the Google Structured Testing Tool.) I'm trying to create the JSON-LD code to add to a page that has multiple products for sale.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@graph": [
{
  "@type": “Product”,
  "name": “tshirt",
  “description”: "test copy 1.”,
  “image”: “image.jpg”
},
{
  "@type": “Product”,
  "name": “tshirt 2",
  “description”: "test copy 2.”,
  “image”: “image2.jpg”
}
]
}
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `“` instead of `"` in some places.

Replacing these, your snippet validates:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@graph": [
{
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "tshirt",
  "description": "test copy 1.",
  "image": "image.jpg"
},
{
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "tshirt 2",
  "description": "test copy 2.",
  "image": "image2.jpg"
}
]
}
</script>
```

**Update:** this snippet doesn't validate by using [Google Rich Results Test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?id=uFt4nco5q4smstE14zONtw) anymore. Schema is being actively developed, so sometimes the requirements change after a while. For a list of products, Google is suggesting so called [carousel](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/carousel).